# E1120:No value for argument 'y' in function call on Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am building a neural network with tensorflow and this is the code I am working with -

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data", one_hot = True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10 
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data): 
    hidden_layer_1 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(784,n_nodes_hl1)),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_nodes_hl1))}
    hidden_layer_2 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2)),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_nodes_hl2))}
    hidden_layer_3 = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3)),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_nodes_hl3))}
    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_nodes_hl3, n_classes)),
                'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(n_classes))}

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_layer_1['weights']) + hidden_layer_1['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_layer_2['weights']) + hidden_layer_2['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_layer_3['weights']) + hidden_layer_3['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights'] + output_layer['biases'])
    return output
```

the lines with tf.add(lines) show the error "E1120:No value for argument 'y' in function call".
I am using pytlint linter on vscode. May be it's a linter issue. 
Does anyone have any suggestion how to resolve this

Comment: Do you get any errors while compiling ? `pylint` on vscode does not always recognizes modules and it's normal to have those.

Comment: made some error in syntax. fixed them and it worked. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function add takes 2 arguments. 
In the line `tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_layer_1['weights']) + hidden_layer_1['biases'])` you are trying to use the function `add` and using the `+` too.
Either do 
`tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_layer_1['weights']), hidden_layer_1['biases'])` 
or
 `tf.matmul(data,hidden_layer_1['weights']) + hidden_layer_1['biases']`.